# Deploying MVC3 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-deployment-project, web-deployment

Good day all, I am trying to deploy my ASP.NET MVC3 app to my webserver. This is what I've done:

1. Uploaded all the project to the web server
2. Created a new empty DB, ran SQL scripts to create the tables and PKs
3. Modified the web.config file's connectionString attribute to point to the online DB
4. added `customErrors mode="On"` to web.config

Here is what error I get:

**Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.**

> System.InvalidOperationException: The cast to value type 'Int32'
>   failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result
>   type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Here is my code for the page I am requesting:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Last game is #" + this.getLastGameId();
    return View();
}

public int getLastGameId()
{
    using (HockeyStatsEntities context = new HockeyStatsEntities())
    {
        return context.Dim_Game.Select(g => g.Game_id).Max();
    }
}
```

I am guessing this is because the tables are empty so that when my query to the db is returning null, that generates the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Max()` throws this exception if there aren't any rows.

You can fix that by casting `game_id` to an `int?`, which will cause `Max()` to return `null`.
You could also call `.DefaultIfEmpty()`.

Comment: Calling `.DefaultIfEmpty()` on what?

Comment: @JFB: On the `Select()` query.